# filter specific touch events

Tags: android, touch

Is is possible for a service to intercept all touch events for all other apps and disable a specific touch event to propagate like we do in sms broadcast receivers?

Comment: Why'd you want to do so, creating virus kinda stuff, huh?
Whatsover, It's not possible, unless you customize Android OS:P

Comment: Ignorance is Bliss;) You can'd it as it says here [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)